# Code First Constraint Violation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I am having trouble deleting objects in an EF Code First (new DB) without violating a foreign key constraint.

I have three classes, Job, Ticket, and Notes.  Job has 0,1 Tickets and many Notes. I would like to delete a job (and its corrosponding ticket/notes) with db.Job.Remove(job) but that leads to a FK violation between Job and Ticket.  How should I structure/annotate the classes?

Thanks in advance.
The following snippet defines the objects/relationships:

```
public WorkflowEntities() : base("CodeFirstWorkflow") { }

    public DbSet<Job> Job { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // Should create a 1:0,1 between Job and Ticket with ticket being optional
        modelBuilder.Entity<Ticket>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.Job)
            .WithOptional(e => e.Ticket);
    }
}

public class Job {
    public int JobId { get; set; }

    public virtual Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Notes> Notes { get; set; }
}

public class Ticket {
    public int TicketId { get; set; }
    public int JobId { get; set; }

    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
}

public class Notes {
    public int NotesId { get; set; }
    public int JobId { get; set; }

    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure this from `Job` side:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Job>()
.HasMany(p => p.Ticket)
.WithRequired()
.HasForeignKey(c => c.JobId)
.WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I modified your solution because my job can only have 1 (or 0) tickets.  The solution was:   
    modelBuilder.Entity<Job>()
        .HasOptional<Ticket>(p => p.Ticket)
        .WithRequired()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);